# MoneroGUI problem re-installing

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, download

I have used Monero GUI wallet a few times just to buy XMR with no problems and then use them to buy online.
This time, however, it showed unblocked and blocked balance despite a transaction going thru as per past transactions.
Then the balance disappeared and I tried uninstalling and re-installing but I just get the initial page with the flag globe.
What should I do?
To anyone who replies, please keep it simple, I'm no expert or technician!
Thanks

Comment: OK I've got back into my wallet but no balance and network status is "starting the node" but goes no further...